# Como pegar um TextBox de um Accordion que foi gerado dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Segue o codigo de como crio o Accordion

```
   private void CarregaAccordionCarros()
   {                        
                //DataTable da Consulta
                var dtTable = GetDataCarro();


                AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane AccordionPane = null;
                Table tabela = null;

                foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
                {                    
                    AccordionPane = new AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane();
                    Label label;                    

                    label = new Label();
                    label.Text = dtRow[1].ToString();

                    //Head
                    AccordionPane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(label);

                    var textBox = new TextBox();
                    textBox.ID = "TextBoxCarro";
                    textBox.Text = dtRow[2].ToString();

                    var td = new TableCell();                    
                    td.Controls.Add(textBox);

                    var tr = new TableRow();
                    tr.Controls.Add(td);

                    tabela = new Table();   
                    tabela.Controls.Add(tr);

                    //Content
                    AccordionPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(tabela);

                    //Accordion
                    AccordionPergJustificativa.Panes.Add(AccordionPane);

                }
            }
```

Aqui o Evento no qual eu pretendo pegar os valores dos TextBox.

> **AccordionCarros.Panes sempre vem == 0**

```
protected void ButtonSalvarCarro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
        {           
            foreach (AccordionPane panes in AccordionCarros.Panes)
            {
                var textBox = (TextBox)panes.FindControl("TextBoxCarro");
                var str1 = textBox.Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }            
}
```

> Deixei o **Try Catch** no codigo, pq aqui não da exceção nenhuma,
>   porem verificando pelo imediate concigo ver que o
>   AccordionCarros.Panes sempre vem zerado.

Comment: Por que você usou esse `try-catch` que não faz nada?

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. Faltou explicar o porque do try Catch. Agora eu já editei a pergunta.

Comment: @alexanderPataki tens como postar o `Page_Load` da tua página, pois dependendo de como tu carrega o teu `acordion` ao acionar o `button` tu pode estar perdendo as informações do `viewstate`

Comment: Outra coisa que já identifiquei, não estou encontrando onde no teu método `CarregaAccordionCarros` é criado o `TextBoxCarro`, terás que nomear os teus componentes na hora que adiciona eles no `Accordion`
`label.ID = "NomeDoLabel";`

Comment: @PabloVargas Eu editei o codigo novamente para mostrar onde eu coloco o id do textbox. No Page_Load, não tem nada por que eu carrego o Accordion a partir de um evento de um botão.

Comment: Então, tenta no teu `ButtonSalvarCarro_Click` chamar novamente o `CarregaAccordionCarros`, isso antes do `foreach`

Comment: @PabloVargas Foi um boa ideia, visto que ele iria criar tudo novamente. Mas também não deu certo.

Comment: @alexanderPataki, tu usa algum `UpdatePanel`? Posta o código `aspx` se possivel.